# ACTION_SHUTDOWN broadcastreceiver from android doesn't work at all

Tags: android

I'm trying to make beep sound when android device power on and shutdown.
Power on receiver works perfect but shutdown doesn't.
I made Broadcastreceiver detect Intent.BOOT_COMPLETED and Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN but only ACTION_SHUTDOWN doesn't work.

Below is manifest for shutdown receiver :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AutoRun"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And below is my AutoRun.java code :

```
public class AutoRun extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ToneGenerator tone = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5, 50);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) { // "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"
        Log.d("AUTO RUN", "Power Off");
        tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5, 100);
    }
}
```

}

I don't understand why boot_completed works but shutdown doesn't.
Any advice of opinion must be great helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers) for broadcast behavior

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

Finally, you can get action `BOOT_COMPLETED` when declare by `Manifest` but action `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` you have to `Context#registerReceiver` in your app (check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SHUTDOWN)).

Comment: Thanks for advice. I checked links you suggests. But after all those trials, it seems like broadcastreceiver can't get any broadcast from ACTION_SHUTDOWN. 
I made JopIntentService and made that work on just button click and broadcast_power off.
On button click it works fine but broadcast_poweroff wasn't even detected(I made Log for it).
I should try for another way to detect ACTION_SHUTDOWN.
Thanks!